# preg_replace for fractions in php

Tags: php, preg-replace, html-entities

Following is the text which contains fractional number **½**, i wants to convert it into **1/2**, for example:

> "**½ frozen banana**"

I tried with following functions:
`htmlentities()`,`htmlspecialchars()`,`htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');`, but it is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple string replace

```
$string =  "½ frozen banana";
echo str_replace('½','1/2',$string);
```

Output

```
1/2 frozen banana
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_replace:

```
<?php
$str = "½ frozen banana";
echo preg_replace('/½/', '1/2', $str);
```

Outputs:

```
1/2 frozen banana
```

Answer (score 0):

@maxhb and @Philipp Palmtag :Thanks, Above both the codes work fine when i am storing string in separate variable.
But when i am storing database value in array variable it is not getting converted so tried with ASCII code conversion.

$test = str_replace(array(chr(189),chr(188),chr(190)), array("1/2","1/4","3/4"), $testString);